# Unity3d - Evaluate enclosed rooms by walls components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on Sims-like building system.
I am at the point where I can create walls at runtime, but my problem is that I need to know when a list of adjacent walls create a well-enclosed room.

My code so far is pretty messy, so apologies if I don't provide any.
The setup is pretty simple, it is 3D environment where each wall is just a cube (see image below).

[image]

The game should allow players to build their own rooms made by walls prefabs (again, they are just cubes stiled as walls).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This is effectively a pathfinding problem of trying to find a path to the "outside." What counts as "outside" and what counts as "wall" (presumably a door counts as a wall for the purposes of "well enclosed room") dictates how you write the pathfinder.

Comment: @Draco18s , thanks for your suggestion. Any idea where I could find an implementation for this? I know pathfinding is a pretty vast subject. An implementation in Unity would be great.

Comment: I don't know if an off-the-shelf solution will work. Its going to depend a lot on your specific setup.

Comment: @Draco18s I updated my question with some more details about my setup.